# Angular + Nginx + Kubernetes - Deployment on Sub Directory Problem

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, deployment, production

When deploying my Angular application to production I'm having an issue where my application can't see/use the bundled scripts generated on build (runtime, main, css, etc.)

### Background:

I have a URL that two Angular apps are supposed to run off of.

1. example.com
2. example.com/subroute

Application #1 works great and as expected.

Application #2 seems to find the correct index.html file when I go to the URL, but it cannot find any of the created scripts (https://example.com/subroute/runtime-es2015.ad3f6d66c5c633672c3c.js).

Any ideas on what else I can try here? Thank you in advance!

### UPDATE #1:

If I change the kubernetes ingress config to the following, I am able to get to my app, but now just can't hit the expected /subroute/api route.

For example, I can hit https://example.com/subroute and my app loads as intended, but if I do a GET request to https://example.com/subroute/api/entity, I get a 404.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: team-webapp-public-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /subroute(/($|.*))?
            backend:
              serviceName: example-subroute-frontend-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /subroute/api/
            backend:
              serviceName: API-service
              servicePort: 9872
```

### App #2 Angular Config

```
npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration production --buildOptimizer=true --base-href '/subroute/' --deployUrl '/subroute/'
```

### App #2 Nginx Config

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/json           max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
  default_type text/html;
  listen 80;
  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
  expires $expires;
  gzip  on;
}
```

### App #2 Kubernetes Config

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: team-webapp-public-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /subroute/
            backend:
              serviceName: example-subroute-frontend-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /subroute/api/
            backend:
              serviceName: API-service
              servicePort: 9872
```

Comment: Added an update. Able to view the app, just can't get the API portion to map correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the final step was to add a servlet path context to my Spring Boot Service that was running. Everything works as intended now!